# Image map hover code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, imagemap

I have the following image mapping code:

```
<div class="fce75" data-close-text="Κλείσιμο" style="position:relative">
    <img alt=""  src="img/imagemap_3.png" usemap="#map-16682" > <map id="#map-16682" name="map-16682">
        <area coords="492,758,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16384" shape="circle">
        <area coords="550,626,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16442" shape="circle">
        <area coords="649,1050,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16387" shape="circle">
        <area coords="816,691,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16444" shape="circle">
        <area coords="1071,1257,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16441" shape="circle">
        <area coords="1080,889,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16436" shape="circle">
        <area coords="1218,380,38" href="/roiplon/endeixeis/#c16423" shape="circle">
        <a class="imageMapHighlight" style="display: none; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"></a>
    </map>
</div>
```

I am using the rwdImageMaps plugin and i initialize it like so:

```
$('.fce75 > img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
```

and then i have the following hover code:

```
$('.fce75 area').hover(function(){

        var coords = $(this).attr("coords").split(',');
        var x = coords[0],
            y = coords[1],
            r = coords[2];

        $(this).closest('.fce75').find('.imageMapHighlight').css(
            {
                left: x - (r) + 'px',
                top: y - (r) + 'px',
                width: r*2 + 'px',
                height: r*2 + 'px',
                display: 'block',
            }
        ).attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));

    }, function(){

    })
```

I have imported the jQuery and also the rwdImageMaps(); plugin , but somehow this still won't work .. Why ? [HERE](http://roiplon-gr-dev.indegene.com/el-gr/roiplon/%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BE%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82) is the page i have tried to integrate the code into , but somehow i am not able to get the hover code working.

Woudl appreciate any help.

Comment: are you sure that `$('.fce75 area')` is selecting the element correctly ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes `$('.fce75 area').length` gives me `7` , so i guess it does :)

Comment: since `hover()` is a shortcut for `mouseenter()`and `mouseleave()`, have you tried those two separated and it also don't work?

Comment: @CalvinNunes sure will try that ! thanks .

Comment: I just giving tips, because for real, I don't know if this will work, but at least it's a try! :D  another tip: maybe try to apply the hover or mouseenter separatedly for each element: `var elements = $('.fce75 area')` and then loop through `elements` adding the `hover()` for each one `elements[i].hover(...)`

Comment: @CalvinNunes what i did was create a new image map using ::- https://www.image-map.net/ and it worked , i guess the initial coordinates were wrong and that was the issue , i had copied the initial image map from a another site doing inspect element and i beleive the orordinates were already manipulated in the inspect element , the key i beleive is to have the initial coordinates right , then the responsive image mapping plugin will do the rest ! Thanks for your help though ! much appreciated mate :)